# 16.04 ubuntu only shows wallpaper after login

Tags: unity, virtualbox, login, desktop-background

I have been using ubuntu for a month and everything is just fine. However, when I try to open my ubuntu today, it suddenly shows nothing but my wallpaper after login, no menu or launcher. And it shows a message that vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running, exiting. And whatever I type in terminal, it just says sudo: unable to resolve host, connection refuesd. My ubuntu version is 16.04. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: please show a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)